# Is there a way to list all site permissions from a parent site to the sub-sites from one place?

Tags: permissions

I am trying to find out all of a complex site permissions.  Those varie depending of the sub-site and I want to make sure 100% are reviewed so the best way would be to have one report and to mark it as we go down. The only solution I know of involves going through the sub-sites one by one and look at the permissions - that's what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: There are 3rd party tools that allow you to look at all the permissions as a whole, and one I can think of is the Access Checker. I'm not saying it's the answer, that's why I put it as a comment, but it would directly solve your issue. Just giving you an option... http://accesschecker.codeplex.com/

Comment: let me know how that works for you.

Comment: [Idera's SharePoint Permission Analyzer](http://www.idera.com/Free-Tools/SharePoint-Permissions-Analyzer/) is free tool from Idera, I hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a tool I developed to list all permissions with site structure for a SharePoint 2013 site. Works with SP 2010 as well. https://sppermissionanalyzer.codeplex.com

Hope this is of some help.